# Tracking Youtube Video Google Tag Manager Youtube API

Tags: google-analytics, youtube-api, google-tag-manager

At the end of my video I added ?rel=0 this allows the video not to show any related videos at the end of the timeline. However now I want to track my video with embedjsapi=1 at the end of the iframe url like this.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/EGnK8zMKWLs?rel=0embedjsapi=1

do i need to put the (&) sybmol between the two rel=0 & embedjsapi=1 or is the link above ok?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, generally speaking, you need separate query parameters by an ampersand (&):

`https://www.youtube.com/embed/EGnK8zMKWLs?rel=0&embedjsapi=1`